# Linear Algebra: The sum of dot-products summarized in a matrix matrix product

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

While reading a section on orthogonal matrices, where $\vec{u}_1, ..., \vec{u}_n$ is an orthonormal set of vectors, I find the equation

$$(\vec{u}_1\vec{u}_1^t + ... + \vec{u}_n\vec{u}_n^t)\vec{x}= \begin{bmatrix}
| & ... & | \\
\vec{u}_1 & ... & \vec{u}_n \\
| & ... & | 
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
-\vec{u}_1^t-\\
...\\
-\vec{u}_n^t-\end{bmatrix}\vec{x}$$

Now I'm familiar with summarizing a linear combination of vectors by a matrix-vector product, but in doing so I use my concept of the dot product between a row vector in the matrix and the column vector written to the right.  This is related to how, in the matrix product, you're basically doing a bunch of dot-products between rows in the left matrix and columns in the right.

Here is something different though, and I'm not sure how I ought to think about it.  The columns are written in the left matrix and rows in the right.  I don't see how this is consistent with the dot-product view of matrix products.  I could chase indices by thinking of the coordinate-wise definition of matrix products, but I feel like the author intends for a better more natural way of understanding this equation.

So is there a good column-row understanding of matrix products, which makes the above equation sensible?  Or is the only good way of understanding this by thinking in terms of the coordinate-wise definition of matrix products?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be written as
$$
\pmatrix{ \vec u_1 & \cdots & \vec u_n}
\left[
\pmatrix{ \vec u_1^T \\ \vdots \\ \vec u_n^T}
\vec x
\right],
$$
where the product in brackets are dot products of $x$ and vectors $u_i$. The resulting numbers are then used to get a linear combination of the vectors $u_i$.